# How to animate the disappearance of a component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-redux, react-class-based-component

In my react App I have a class-based parent component **Items**. Inside it renders the child component **Item**.

```
export class Items extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Filters />
                <div className="container__main">
                     this.props.items.map((item) => (
                          <Item key={item.id} item={item} />
                     ))
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

and **Item**

```
export class Item extends Component {

    cmb = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.cmb.current !== null) {
            setTimeout(() => { 
                this.cmb.current.style.transform = "scaleY(1) translateZ(0)"; 
                this.cmb.current.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out"; });
        } else return;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.cmb} className="someClass">
                // some code
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Each component Item is animated after it is mounted or re-mounted. But what is the best way to animate it when it disappears (if the parent component Items doesn't render it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR

> As far as I know there is `onAnimationStart`, `onAnimationEnd` in React

### Answer

You can use `onAnimationStart`, `onAnimationEnd` synthetic event listener and some props like `isShowComponent`, `isHideComponent`

And you can use `unmountComponentAtNode()`, `findDOMNode()` in `react-dom`

### Peseudo Code

```js
   handleAnimationEnd() {
     const node = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this);
     ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(node)
   }
   ...
   render(){
     return (
        <div onAnimtionEnd={this.handleAnimationEnd}>
        /** some code**/
        </div>
     )
   }
```

### ETC

It is not real code but just peseudo! but I think you can do that using this api and event handler!
Good luck!

> If you have any good solution. just hit me with comment!
> It should be helpful to other developer struggling with this issue

### Reference

1. [React Document](https://ko.reactjs.org/docs/events.html)
2. [React Dom Document](https://ko.reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode)
3. [code sandbox exmaple](https://codesandbox.io/s/animation-start-finish-y8oy0?from-embed)
4. [How to Trigger Animation Events using React](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-trigger-animation-events-using-react-a6c3256b21c6)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I decided to use a bunch of two methods: componentDidUpdate and getSnapshotBeforeUpdate to make a smooth movement after updating the list.